# NSSortDescriptor custom alphanumeric order

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray, sql-order-by, comparator, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to sort an NSArray with a custom alphabetically order. The deal is that I have an Array with strings which are containing states of objects.

The available states are `entered, process, ready, done`.

Now when I sort them normally (in alphabetic order), the order would be incorrect (done, entered, process, ready).

I tried the following code to order it the right way:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"state" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 isEqualToString:@"entered"] && [obj2 isEqualToString:@"process"]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([obj1 isEqualToString:@"process"] && [obj2 isEqualToString:@"entered"]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else if ([obj1 isEqualToString:@"process"] && [obj2 isEqualToString:@"ready"]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([obj1 isEqualToString:@"ready"] && [obj2 isEqualToString:@"process"]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else if ([obj1 isEqualToString:@"ready"] && [obj2 isEqualToString:@"done"]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([obj1 isEqualToString:@"done"] && [obj2 isEqualToString:@"ready"]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

I also tried using just the first letters of the words, but it didn't work too.

When I'm using this comparator, it just don't order resp. the array keeps the "old" order.

What am I dining wrong? Didn't I understand sort comparators right?

Thanks for help, kind regards, Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to answer because I got a lot of code here. I now got the thing running. But there is a *funny* bug :)

```
NSString *str1 = (NSString *)obj1;
NSString *str2 = (NSString *)obj2;

if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"entered"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"progress"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"entered"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"ready"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"entered"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"done"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"progress"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"entered"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"progress"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"ready"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"progress"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"done"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"ready"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"entered"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"ready"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"progress"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"ready"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"done"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"done"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"entered"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"done"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"progress"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
}
else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"done"] && [str2 isEqualToString:@"ready"]) {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
}
else {
    return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Now the bug: When I'm changing the order direction (`ascending:YES / NO`), the direction is right every second time I'm ordering `ascending:YES` (entered, progress, ready, done). Else it is a bit wrong: entered, progress, done, ready.

Does anybody can imagine why or has a solution for that? It's not a serious bug but I want to fix it though.

Thanks, Mundi, but I think I'll keep using my fuzzy style. I'm quite new to Cocoa / Objective C and this way makes more sense for me, right now. Nevertheless thanks for your effort!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your scheme with strings is not suitable for what you are trying to do. To record states it is much better to use a different data model and take care of the appropriate strings in the view.

A common implementation involves an `enum`, which automatically increments if you define it like this:

```
typedef enum {
   entered = 0,
   processed,
   ready,
   done
 } State;
```

Sorting now becomes trivial.

Your `state` should be of type `State` which is practically an integer. You will need to wrap it in an `NSNumber` if you want to use NSDictionary or NSArray, but it is certainly more readable if you create a custom object with a `@property` of type `State`.

Comment: Hey Mundi! Great approach, thanks! But now: How could I convert the NSString (with the state names) into an object of type _state_? I can't change the representation from the database, because my App is "just" a iOS wrapper for a web based application. **Thank** though!

Comment: The same way you would do with other JSON or XML "fields". Match them to your custom object's properties one by one. In this case just with a string of if statements perhaps.